# Building a blog in rails -- "show" action and show view whitespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, whitespace

When I view my sample posts in the show.html.erb view, it seems that it ignores whitespace. For example, if I create a post with 2 paragraphs:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."

It will come out like this on the page:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."

How do I make the posts look the way I have entered them? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any WYSIWYG editor in new and edit views?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't rails specific, this is how HTML handles whitespaces. HTML collapses whitespaces. To make them show up you can use `&nbsp;` (non blank space) for spacing between text. `<br>` and `<p>` to space between lines. Or you can put your text inside `<pre>` tags.

See [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/f/blfaqwhitespace.htm) for some info. I'd recommend you brush up on HTML a bit so you can tell when rails is doing something weird or when HTML is tripping you up.

Comment: For returns, `\n` need to be replaced with `<br/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing doing the way Dty suggests might make sense. Long term it might be painful to deal with.

If you want more formatting, I'd suggest saving the raw HTML into the DB and doing something like this in your views:

```
<%= render :inline => post.content %>
```